# What is the best way to implement a constructor/init methods in Go

Tags: go, constructor, init

I have a program as below:

```
package main

//Define declare variables
type Define struct {
    len    int
    breath int
}

//Area calculate area
func (e *Define) Area() (a int) {
    a = e.len * e.breath
    return a
}
```

I call the above program in:

```
package main

func main() {
    y := Define{10, 10}
    x := y.Area()
    print(x)
}
```

I would like make the function `Area()` as part of struct initialization. Currently, I have to create a new object for "Define" ie "y" and then call the method Area. Instead is there a way that Area methods auto calculates once I create the object?

Comment: The name `Define` is a bit strange for your struct?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to call `Area()` after initialization if it doesn't change the state of your struct. Why would you need this in a constructor, if the whole point of a constructor is to return a constructed `Define` which would have it's state changed by something more trivial than initial parameters.

Comment: As pointed out by jacob, your example makes little to no sense, that said, the convention is to define a "constructor" func that begins with `NewXxx`, e.g. `NewDefine` or `NewArea`, and in cases where your package's name matches the type you want to construct then you can stick with just `New`. E.g. say your package is named `area`, then you would define a func called `New` and then other packages that import the `area` package would initialize a new instance with `area.New`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rename Define to something better like Geometry. Usually in Golang, New... is used as a "constructor"

Since you said you wanted area to be autocalculated, include the area as a struct field. Here's how I'd go about it (https://play.golang.org/p/4y6UVTTT34Z):

```
package main

//variables
type Geometry struct {
    len    int
    breath int
    area   int
}

// Constructor
func NewGeometry(len int, breadth int) *Geometry {
    g := &Geometry{len, breadth, Area(len, breadth)}
    return g
}

//Area calculate area
func Area(len, breadth int) (a int) {
    return len * breadth
}

func main() {
    g := NewGeometry(10, 2)
    fmt.Println(g.area)
}
```

Comment: I have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70546752/how-to-make-an-object-of-a-class-and-have-getters-for-struct) where I am confuse on how should I have constructor or init functions in go for my use case. Can you help me with this if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go has the concept of ["Constructors"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) that may cover your use case.  Combined with exporting it allows you to encapsulate initialization by hiding specifics of calculation from callers:

```
package main

//Define declare variables
type Define struct {
    len    int
    breath int
    area   int 
}

func (e Define) Area() int {
    return e.area
}

func NewDefine(l, b int) Define {
   d := Define{
      len: l,
      breath: b,
      area: calculateArea(l, b),
   }
   return d
}
```

The pattern to focus on is the exported `NewX`.  It is extremely common to see constructors named `NewX` which will initialize and return a struct.  The above delegates to an un-exported `calculateArea` function.  Of course there are many different possible ways for you to structure your program.  `calculateArea` still encapsulates the area calculation for trivial unit testing, while hiding it from callers by not exporting it.