# How to make an object of a class and have getters for struct?

Tags: go, struct

I have recently started working with `golang` so having difficulties understanding on how to achieve same thing which I am able to do it easily in `Java` or `C#`. I am trying to make an object of `configmanager` class and when the first time `configmanager` class is called, it should initialize all my configs and store it in memory in some struct object. And then I should have access to `configmanager` object and should be able to access all those configs from my main function using some getters maybe?

Below is my `configmanager` go class. It is very simple for now to make it easier to understand.

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type ClientMetrics struct {
    ClientMetrics []ClientMetric `json:"clientMetrics"`
}
type CustomerData struct {
    Process []string `json:"Process"`
    Mat     []string `json:"Mat"`
}
type ClientMetric struct {
    ClientID     int          `json:"clientId"`
    CustomerData CustomerData `json:"customerData,omitempty"`
    LegCustomer  []int        `json:"legCustomer"`
    OtherIds     []int        `json:"otherIds,omitempty"`
    CatID        int          `json:"catId,omitempty"`
}

func Init(root string) (err error) {
    files, err := utilities.FindFiles(root, "process-data.json")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot find process-data.json file: %v", err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("unable to read file: %v", err)
        }
        var auto ClientMetrics
        json.Unmarshal(body, &auto)

    }

    return nil
}
```

And here is I use it in my main function - This is just basic code just to demonstrate what I am doing but this isn't `production` ready code.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/david/internal/config"
)

func main() {
    root := "/home/Configurations"
    config.Init(root)

  //
}
```

In my above `Init` function, I find `process-data.json` file if it is there on the disk and then load it in memory by deserializing it into `ClientMetrics` object. Everything works fine as shown above.

**Problem Statement**

Since I am coming from `Java` and `C#` background, so my confusion is how can I make an object of `configmanager` class and how should I initialize all my configs during the first time when I call `configmanager` and also have access to `ClientMetrics` struct using some getters. In Java and C#, I used to have constructor where I initialize all these things and then have some getters to access the config. How should I do the same thing in golang.

My main confusion is do we have constuctors in go and how should I make getters to access struct object in my main function? I am just looking for better design in go and how should I do my above code in golang?

**Update**

I think I wasn't able to explain properly. I have X (let's suppose 5 for now) different json files in a folder and each of those json files needs to have their own struct because they are totally different json files. My `configmanager` file will be responsible to load all those 5 json files into their own struct and then I should be able to access all those 5 `structs` and their fields from the object of `configmanager`. All this should happen during the initialization of `configmanager` class when it is called for the first time.

Here is just an example where I have bunch of json files in their own corresponding folder `(folderX)`. I have three categories of files `(clientMap-*.json, dataMap-*.json, process-data.json)` as shown below.

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── clientMap-123.json
│   ├── clientMap-987.json
│   ├── clientMap-7161.json
├── folder2
│   ├── dataMap-18271.json
│   ├── dataMap-12921.json
│   ├── dataMap-98121.json
└── folder3
    ├── process-data.json
```

Now I need to read all these files `(clientMap-*.json, dataMap-*.json, process-data.json)` in their own struct. And I should able to use `configmanager` class to get corresponding struct and their fields too after unmarshalling.

For example: Read `clientMap-*.json` files.

```
files, err := utilities.FindFiles(root, "clientMap-*.json")
// load all clientMap-*.json files in its own struct after unmarshalling
```

Similarly for `dataMap-*.json` files

```
files, err := utilities.FindFiles(root, "dataMap-*.json")
// load all dataMap-*.json files in its own struct after unmarshalling
```

Also for `process-data.json` files

```
files, err := utilities.FindFiles(root, "process-data.json")
// load all process-data.json files in its own struct after unmarshalling
```

My `FindFiles` method will find all the files even with `regex` like above. `files` variable is an array containing list of all files matching particular pattern. Now I can create `ConfigManager` struct type holding all other `structs` for my config but I am trying to find a solution which is easily extensible so that in future if I add any other json file category it should be able to extend easily. What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought earlier after reading lot of go tutorials but my use case is slightly different as I can have let's say 10 different configs (files) and each of those configs can have their own structs since it's a different configs so I need to have separate struct for them so how can I do this in your suggestion? Also even if we can do that how will unmarshal works then? @CeriseLimón

Comment: And how would you do that in Java or C#? Are you saying there is still one class, but with overloaded constructors? If so, in Go that can be done with one struct and different functions (each function returns a pointer/reference but just builds the initilaises the struct in a different way).

Comment: Sounds to me that ConfigManager should have a slice containing all the objects marshalled from the JSON. A slice (or map) would be needed since you dont know how many such files there can be. The composition shown in VonC's answer could also be of help to you.

Comment: In starting I will have let's say 5 json files and they need to be unmarshalled into their own struct so total 5 struct basically and `ConfigManager` should be responsible to do all that and provide mechanism to return each of those struct and their fields. Can you provide an example with slice which can be extended easily if needed? I already responded to VonC answer as well. Problem is I cannot modify my json to add type into it. Let me know if that can still be extended for my use case. @Sangam

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have updated my question to add more details to it. Let me know if that makes sense now.

Comment: Yes as of now it just does nothing in terms of return as I wasn't sure but init should return an object of `ConfigManager` which should have access to multiple structs for each json type. Let's suppose if we have total 5 different json. Just like in any other programming language, I will have 5 different classes for each unique json file category and will populate all those 5 classes after deserializing their own json into them. Now my ConfigManager class will provide an object of all those 5 class that I can return from the getters. I am looking to do something similar here @CeriseLimón

Comment: `process-data.json` will read into `ClientMetrics` array. `clientMap-*.json` will read into let's say `ClientMap` array. `dataMap-*.json` will read into let's say `DataMap` array. Now init should return `ConfigManager` object after loading all these json files into their appropriate struct which contains all these structs basically. @CeriseLimón

Comment: Is https://go.dev/play/p/TBIRb33ZCCW something like what you are looking for?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes exactly and this is just for one config which is `process-data.json` file. We deserialize `process-data.json` into `ClientMetrics` array and construct `Manager` object which has `ClientMetrics` object in it.  Now imagine if I have 4 more different json files then I need to modify manager struct to add 4 more different array type and accordingly I need to modify newManager function too which will look ugly. Can you move this conversation to chat as I am unable to do it and I can add more details there as in chatting it will be come easier to show code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Does it make sense on my previous reply? You still around to help me with my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is hard to answer because you kind of forgot to ask one in a definitive way, so I will start my answer by extracting a question based on what you wrote. I believe we can do so from this:

> **Problem Statement**
>
> [...] my confusion is how can I make an object of `configmanager` class and how should I initialize all my configs during the first time when I call `configmanager` and also have access to `ClientMetrics` struct using some getters

I believe the real question here is "How do I separate the concern of reading and unmarshalling the files from the concern of storing the results for my program to use?".

It's common to separate concerns by breaking things up into multiple functions/methods, which you have already done to some extent. Storage however is strictly a matter of types, so we need a type capable of holding the results. I'll use this opportunity to omit the word `Manager` from the type's name, because all it does is to provide useless abstraction. This type does not manage the config. It *is* the config, in that it contains *all* of the config.

```golang
type Config struct {
    ClientMapConfigs   []ClientMapConfig
    DataMapConfigs     []DataMapConfig
    ProcessDataConfigs []ProcessDataConfig
}
```

Notice the fields start with an upper-case letter, making them public. This communicates that there could be nonsense in there, as nothing is protected from writes, which aligns with the fact that we read this data from files. A correct program must validate this data before using it. You could then communicate the validity of the validated data in the variable name.

```golang
func main() {
    validConfig := getValidConfig("path/to/dir")
    // ...
}

func getValidConfig(configDirectoryPath string) *Config {
    config, err := NewConfigFromConfigDirectory(configDirectoryPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to read config from dir '%s': %v\n", configDirectoryPath, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if err = ValidateConfig(config); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Config from dir '%s' failed to validate: %v\n", configDirectoryPath, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func NewConfigFromConfigDirectory(configDirectoryPath string) *Config {
    // <- read individual configs and add to slices here

    return &Config{ // This is the closest to a "constructor" that Go has.
        ClientMapConfigs: clientMapConfigs,
        DataMapConfigs: dataMapConfigs,
        ProcessDataConfigs: processDataConfigs,
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no imminent need for the functions validating and reading the config to have a receiver, i.e. be a method of a struct. They're fine as standalone functions until your requirements change in ways which demand the introduction of statefulness for either logic.

Also I use exit code `1` for the error-cases here, because Golang uses code `2` when the program terminates due to a panic. The former can be thought of as a problem with the environment, while the later indicates a problem within the program itself. It's a useful distinction to make, and aligns with the semantics of `Exception` versus `RuntimeException` which you may know from Java.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yeah I kinda messed up while writing the question but I am glad you understood what I want. This looks good but my main confusion is also around here `// <- read individual configs and add to slices here`. How can I do this properly and efficiently? I mean I can have individual methods for each file category and read them but if I add more file category then it will get crowded and look ugly. Is there any better way to handle this? If you can provide an example then it will be of great help.

Comment: I understand your problem now. Alas, you cannot do better than what you are thinking, because Go does not have generics (yet). The pointer you provide to `Unmarshal()` must be a pointer to the concrete type you ultimately want, so you have to write the lines of code needed to make it happen, for every type of file you have. In Java such method would simply accept `Object`, but there is no inheritance in Go, only embedding, so it cannot be done.

Comment: I see. Got it now. That clears things up for me. Also if you don't mind can you add some dummy examples on how can I add individual configs to slices? `// <- read individual configs and add to slices here` This will help me understand that what I am thinking is right way.

Comment: You'll need the `append()` built-in function. It is covered by the tour of go, which is a good practice session you should take from start to finish: https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/15 Tour starts at https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1

Comment: I have some confusion here. `The first parameter s of append is a slice of type T, and the rest are T values to append to the slice.` In my case what will be `T` here? That's where I was confuse. If you can add some examples then it can help me a lot for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

> I can have let's say 10 different configs (files) and each of those configs can have their own structs since it's a different configs so I need to have separate struct for them

That looks like dynamic JSON struct unmarshalling, which was presented in 2015 by [John Asmuth](https://twitter.com/skelterjohn) in [decoding with mixed structures](https://gowithconfidence-blog.tumblr.com/post/119295279861/decoding-with-mixed-structures)

You can run the [following example here](https://go.dev/play/p/8iYsgE-scQ).

```golang
type Dog struct {
  Name     string
  Frisbees int
}
type Cat struct {
  Name    string
  Strings int
}
type RawAnimal struct {
  Type string
  Cat
  Dog
}
type Animal RawAnimal
func (a *Animal) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, (*RawAnimal)(a)); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  switch a.Type {
  case "cat":
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &a.Cat)
  case "dog":
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &a.Dog)
  }
  return fmt.Errorf("unknown type %q", a.Type)
}
```

From there, your ConfigManager will instantiate the right Config structure, depending on the raw JSON read.

Comment: Note: on direct struct instantiation vs. constructor in Go: https://pauldigian.hashnode.dev/advanced-go-choosing-between-a-constructor-and-declaring-the-type

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thanks a lot for your help. I updated my question at the end to explain exactly what I am looking for. My `ConfigManager` should instantiate all 5 different configs into its own struct and should provide a mechanism to access all those struct as well. In your example you think I have bunch of similar json configs with different type but that is not the case. In my case, `ConfigManager` is responsible to instantiate all X configs into its own struct by reading it from the disk using the fileName or filePattern already defined. Let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: Just like in any other programming language, I will have 5 different classes for each unique json file category and will populate all those 5 classes after deserializing their own json into them. Now my `ConfigManager` class will provide an object of all those 5 class that I can return from the getters.

Comment: Basically each struct will have its own json file (or files) on the disk. Because they are totally different json files. My `ConfigManager` class will be responsible to load all those json files into its own struct and should provide mechanism to access each struct and their fields too.

Comment: @user1950349 OK. That make sense. Still, as "a solution which is easily extensible so that in future if I add any other json file", I like my proposition of one JSON unmarshaller able to generate different classes from different JSON files.

Comment: hmmm how can I do that for my case? I cannot modify my json files btw to add any type as a field since it's a legacy system. @VonC

Comment: @user1950349 OK, then it is not a good fit indeed. Hopefully, your edited question will attract better answers.

Comment: Thanks @VonC for your help. Any other ideas you have that is suited to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble is that you're looking at Go from a Java/C# perspective and thus struggling to make sense of the features. If you have the time, then I would suggest that you go thru some Go tutorials or books before you start coding (this one is pretty good: [https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0134190440](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134190440))

To answer your question directly, what you need to do is to create a function which returns a pointer to an object of the struct (see here for a simple example: https://gobyexample.com/structs)

Taking ClientMetric as an example:

```
func NewClientMetric(ClientID int, CustomerData CustomerData, LegCustomer []int, OtherIds []int, CatID int) (*ClientMetric, error) {

//validate your inputs
//in case of errors, create and error message in the variable err and then: return nil, err
//other code which would go into a typical constructor would go here

return &ClientMetric{ClientID,CustomerData, LegCustomer, OtherIds, CatID}, nil
}
```

In this case, the function `NewClientMetric` is the *constructor* and it returns a pointer/reference to the newly created object. It also returns an error object, which is the same as saying that the constructor throws exceptions. Just as you would need to use try/catch in Java, you would need to check to handle the err variable returned by this function.

You would need to make similar functions for each of your types.

As for getters & setters, generally speaking, that should be avoided in Go. You can access the attributes of a struct directly. A function (like a getter) is only useful if you're going to do something to the attribute before returning it. Something like this:

```
type Customer struct {
FirstName string
LastName string
}

func (this *Customer) GetFullName() string {
return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName
}
```

and these can then be accessed like this:

```
var customer *Customer
customer = &Customer{"John","Smith")
fmt.Println(customer.FirstName)
fmt.Println(customer.LastName)
fmt.Println(customer.GetFullName())
```

Please note that attributes, functions and methods which begin with a capital letter are public, the others are private. If `FirstName` was written as `firstName`, it would not be accessible outside the package in which it was declared.

Please do note that I'm not checking for errors if the pointer is null/nil, but that is always recommended.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thanks a lot for your help. I updated my question at the end to explain exactly what I am looking for. My `ConfigManager` should instantiate all 5 different configs into its own struct and should provide a mechanism to access all those struct as well. In my case, `ConfigManager` is responsible to instantiate all X configs into its own struct by reading it from the disk using the fileName or filePattern already defined. Let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: Basically each struct will have its own json file (or files) on the disk. Because they are totally different json files. My `ConfigManager` class will be responsible to load all those json files into its own struct and should provide mechanism to access each struct and their fields too.